# Background image missing in SSRS subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

My report has a background image embedded in it and it is correctly reflecting on the report server but when I run the subscription, the image does not come with the email. What are the additional settings that I would need to do to get this image in the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the properties of the image, is the source external?

if yes, is the url is valid (and accessible) from where you open the email?

Comment: I have tried setting it as external and embedded but it is not working in either of the case. The image is accessible from the email.

Comment: it seems to be a known issue. can you also see the image when you click on the "show in web browser" link on the top of the email? https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/928975/ssrs-background-image-doesnt-display-in-subscription-email-when-sent-as-html